# Ruby combine array of hashes with the same key and multiple values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following array which is actually a combination of two arrays. My goal is that the 2 hashes with employeeId of 898989 could be combined and that I could add their counts together and change their type to both. I tried the code below which is close to what I want, however I lose the other values of my hashes. Is there any easy way to map all of the values and do manipulation like adding the counts like I want?

```
combined = [{"@rid"=>"#-2:1", "employeeId"=>   "898989", "count"=>1, :type=>"wiki"  },
       {"@rid"=>"#-2:3", "employeeId"=>  "2423213", "count"=>7, :type=>"search"},
       {"@rid"=>"#-2:2", "employeeId"=>   "555555", "count"=>2, :type=>"search"},
       {"@rid"=>"#-2:5", "employeeId"=>   "898989", "count"=>2, :type=>"search"},
       {"@rid"=>"#-2:1", "employeeId"=>  "5453454", "count"=>1, :type=>"search"},
       {"@rid"=>"#-2:4", "employeeId"=>"987654321", "count"=>1, :type=>"search"}]

merged_array_hash = combined.group_by { |h1| h1["employeeId"] }.map do |k,v|
    { "employeeId" => k, :types =>  v.map { |h2| h2[:type] }.join(", ") }
end
```

merged_array_hash ends up being:

```
[{employeeId: "898989",types: "wiki, search"},
{employeeId: "2423213",types: "search"},
{employeeId: "555555",types: "search"},
{employeeId: "5453454",types:"search"},
{employeeId: "987654321",types: "search"}]
```

What I'm looking to get:

```
[{employeeId: "898989",type: "both", count: 2},
{employeeId: "2423213",type: "search", count: 7},
{employeeId: "555555",type: "search", count: 2},
{employeeId: "5453454",type:"search", count: 1},
{employeeId: "987654321",type: "search", count: 1}]
```

Comment: This code doesn't run.  Can you explain what the variables `wiki` and `search` are supposed to hold?

Comment: When you give an example please show the desired result as a Ruby object. ("combined = wiki + search" does not satisfy that requirement.) Also, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (here there would be just one, perhaps `arr = [ { "@arid"=>...}, {...} ]`). That way readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them, and everyone will use the same variable names.

Comment: I trust you don't mind the edit I did. I merely reformatted so that readers wouldn't have to scroll horizontally, and added a variable name for the array.

Comment: Sorry wiki and search were just there to show that I was combining 2 arrays. I updated the code above to just name the sample data array combined and then what I was doing to it.

Comment: You haven;t shown the value of `merged_array_hash`. If it's what you want, what's your question? If not, please show it's value and show explain what you want instead.

Comment: Added the final result. As you can see it does combine them, however I'm not sure how to actually show the other values of the hash. So what I'm looking for is to combine the 2 hashes with the same key and also implement some logic so that I can include the counts added together and instead of types with both values, just have a new type of "both".

Comment: If `arr` is the array "What I'm looking to get": `arr.first #=> { employeeId: "898989",type: "both", count: 2 }`, so `arr.first[:count] #=> 2`. Why is that `2` (rather than, say, `1+2 #=> 3`)? `Also, if there were three or more hashes in `arr` with the same value of `:employeeld`, would the value of `:type` in the desired result still be `"both"`?

Comment: You are correct, that was an error on my part the count should be 3. There will only ever be at most 2 duplicates in the array since there will be at most one instance of that username in each of the 2 arrays I initially combine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not beautiful, but it will get the job done:

```
combined.group_by { |h1| h1["employeeId"] }.map do |k,v|
  types = v.map { |h2| h2[:type] }  
  count = v.sum { |x| x['count'] } 

  { employeeId: k, 
    types: (types.length == 1 ? types[0] : 'both'), 
    count: count }  

end  

=> [{:employeeId =>"898989", :types=>"both", :count=>3},
    {:employeeId =>"2423213", :types=>"search", :count=>7},
    {:employeeId =>"555555", :types=>"search", :count=>2},
    {:employeeId =>"5453454", :types=>"search", :count=>1},
    {:employeeId =>"987654321", :types=>"search", :count=>1}]
```

Comment: I implemented this solution and it seems to do the trick. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Also not beautiful, will also get the job done, potentially more readable

```
hash = {}
combined.each do |h|
  employeeId, count, type = h.values_at("employeeId", "count", :type)
  if hash.include? employeeId
    hash[employeeId][:count] += count
    hash[employeeId][:type] = "both"  #assumes duplicates can only occur if item is in both lists
  else
    hash[employeeId] = { :employeeId => employeeId, :type => type, :count => count }
  end
end
hash.values
```

Testing:

```
[{:employeeId=>"898989", :type=>"both", :count=>3},
{:employeeId=>"2423213", :type=>"search", :count=>7},
{:employeeId=>"555555", :type=>"search", :count=>2},
{:employeeId=>"5453454", :type=>"search", :count=>1},
{:employeeId=>"987654321", :type=>"search", :count=>1}]
```